# Android install works from Visual Studio, fails to launch when installed using adb.exe

Tags: android, visual-studio, apk, adb

I have an Android app built using `Visual Studio`. If I hit F5 to run it, it builds, deploys and runs just fine.
I now want to automate some UI tests so I took the `com.myapp-Signed.apk` out of the `/bin/debug` folder and copied it to my UI tests area. I then run the install via ADB against that APK and it installs without a problem, but when I launch it, I get a blank screen. No crash, no output, just a blank white screen.

If I attempt to install the other (unsigned) APK, I get the error:

> Failed to install D:\myAppName\Artefacts\com.myAppName.apk: Failure
>   [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates
>   from /data/app/vmdl1599731502.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of
>   null array]

So I'm assuming the signed .apk is the way to go?

If so, any ideas why I'm only getting a blank screen?

Thanks

Comment: Any solution? I have got the same problem.

Comment: no, still searching on this one :(

Comment: Please be kind to share the solution , We are facing the same issue too

Comment: Solved the issue by signing. It's easy in VS2019.